# How do I make many movable text boxes in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, object, events, event-handling, pygame

My game is a simple drag and drop style game where you simply have to put a term in its respective categories. There are a total of 50 terms to drag and drop in the 4 categories displayed in the background image. 
    I am very frustrated. I cannot find a question/tutorial to simply make text boxes to drag around and place in regions of the background images.
    I would like to make 50 terms that the user can simply drag and drop around the screen.

How do I make that many boxes and add the mouse events to them? 
    I have the following code below:

```
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import *

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1720 
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 1000  
DISPLAY_SIZE = (DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

ANSWERS_WIDTH = 1500
ANSWERS_HEIGHT = 750
ANSWERS_SIZE = (ANSWERS_WIDTH, ANSWERS_HEIGHT)

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Button:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.is_hover = False
        self.default_color = (100,100,100)
        self.hover_color = (255,255,255)
        self.font_color = (0,0,0)
        self.obj = None

    def label(self):
        '''button label font'''
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)
        return font.render(self.text, 1, self.font_color)

    def color(self):
        '''change color when hovering'''
        if self.is_hover:
            return self.hover_color
        else:
            return self.default_color

    def draw(self, screen, mouse, rectcoord, labelcoord):
        '''create rect obj, draw, and change color based on input'''
        self.obj  = pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color(), rectcoord)
        screen.blit(self.label(), labelcoord)

        #change color if mouse over button
        self.check_hover(mouse)

    def check_hover(self, mouse):
        '''adjust is_hover value based on mouse over button - to change hover color'''
        if self.obj.collidepoint(mouse):
            self.is_hover = True 
        else:
            self.is_hover = False

    #def openWin(self, event):
     #   if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      #      if self.obj.collidepoint(event.pos):


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, dx, dy, filename):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = dx
        self.rect.y = dy

        # - or shorter -
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=dx, y=dy)

        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

        self.click = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.x -= 10
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 10
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= 10
        if self.moving_down:
            self.rect.y += 10

        if self.click:
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = False

    def mouse_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.click = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            self.click = False

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- fuctions --- (lower_case names)

    # empty

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init() 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY_SIZE,HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
screen2 = pygame.display.set_mode(ANSWERS_SIZE,HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)

# - objects -

background_image = pygame.image.load("back.png").convert()
#button_to_answers = pygame.image.load("basketball.png").convert()

btn = Button('Button 1')
btn1 = Button('Button 2')


enemy = Enemy(100,400, 'hinatest.jpg')
enemy2 = Enemy(200,200, 'Sora.png')
enemy3 = Enemy(300,100, 'naruto.png')
enemy4 = Enemy(500,000, 'Ichigo.jpg')

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

gameplay = True

while gameplay: 

    # - events -
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameplay = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                gameplay = False

        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         #   if btn.obj.collidepoint(mouse):
          #     print('button 1 clicked')
           #    screen2.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button_to_answers, (1500,720)), (0,0))
            #   pygame.display.flip()

        elif event.type==VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'],HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
            screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(background_image,event.dict['size']),(0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()

            display_coordinates = pygame.display.Info()
            print('current_w = ', display_coordinates.current_w, '\ncurrent_h = ', display_coordinates.current_h, '\n')

        # - objects event handle -
        enemy.mouse_event(event)
        enemy2.mouse_event(event)
        enemy3.mouse_event(event)
        enemy4.mouse_event(event)

    # - updates -

    enemy.update()
    enemy2.update()
    enemy3.update()
    enemy4.update()

    # - draws -

    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (1720,1000)), (0,0))

    btn.draw(screen, mouse, (100,100,100,20), (125,103))

    enemy.draw(screen)
    enemy2.draw(screen)
    enemy3.draw(screen)
    enemy4.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip() 

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(60)

    screen.fill(BLACK)
# - exit -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Note, you won't be able to run the code because of the images I used in mine. You can simply deactivate the images being updated to simply run it, or replace them with stock images to use the drag feature.

Comment: Your code example is pretty long. Better reduce it to the [minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but make sure that it can still be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for the text objects, set its `image` to the surface that `FONT.render` returns and define a `selected` variable that holds the currently selected text sprite.

Now check if the mouse collided with a text sprite in the event loop and if yes, assign it to the `selected` variable. If a `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event occurs, set the `selected.rect.center` to the new `event.pos`. Done.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 42)


class Text(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, text, pos, color, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = FONT.render(text, True, color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(
        Text('hello', (100, 300), pg.Color('steelblue1')),
        Text('world', (250, 300), pg.Color('sienna1')),
        )

    selected = None
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for sprite in all_sprites:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected = sprite
                        break
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                selected = None
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected:
                    selected.rect.center = event.pos

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: This is WAY more simpler than what I had. So simple! So efficient, thank you!